# ListView cannot display item data while getting data from internet using RxJava

Tags: android, listview, rx-java

I am getting some job information from the internet, and preparing to display using Listview. While I use RxJava to deal with multiple thread, and the list item cannot display.[List item cannot display getting data using RxJava](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z91en.png)
And I use some test data, it can display[Use an array as data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtDqv.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ActionBar mActionbar;
private ListView mSeminarList;
private SeminarListAdapter mSeminarListAdapter;
private ArrayList<SeminarListItem> mSeminarData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initToolbar();
    initSlideMenu();
    initListView();
}


private void initToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionbar.setTitle("爱实习  爱工作");
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_menu_white_36dp);
}

private void initSlideMenu() {
    PrimaryDrawerItem priItemHome = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
            .withName("首页");
    SecondaryDrawerItem subItemSeminar = new SecondaryDrawerItem()
            .withName("宣讲信息");
    SecondaryDrawerItem subItemIntern = new SecondaryDrawerItem()
            .withName("实习信息");
    SecondaryDrawerItem subItemJob = new SecondaryDrawerItem()
            .withName("工作信息");

    Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(mToolbar)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    priItemHome, new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    subItemSeminar, subItemIntern, subItemJob
            )
            .build();
}

private void initListView() {
    mSeminarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_seminar);
    mSeminarData = new ArrayList<SeminarListItem>();
//  getListData();
    getListDataTest();
}

private void getListData() {
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Elements>() {

        public void call(Subscriber<? super Elements> subscriber) {
            try {
                String url = "http://xjh.haitou.cc/sh/uni-132";
                Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
                conn.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
                Document doc = conn.get();
                Elements elements = doc.select("tbody tr");
                subscriber.onNext(elements);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Elements>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d("onCompleted", "test");
            if (mSeminarListAdapter == null) {
                mSeminarListAdapter = new SeminarListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, mSeminarData);
            }
            mSeminarList.setAdapter(mSeminarListAdapter);
            mSeminarListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void onNext(Elements elements) {
            for (Element element : elements) {
                String company = element.getElementsByClass("company").text();
                String link = element.select("a").attr("abs:href").toString();
                String time = element.getElementsByClass("hold-ymd").text();
                String address = element.getElementsByClass("text-ellipsis").text();

                SeminarListItem item = new SeminarListItem();
                item.setCompanyName(company);
                item.setTime("举办时间: " + time);
                item.setPlace("举办地点: " + address);
                item.setInfoUrl(link);
                mSeminarData.add(item);
                Log.d("test company name", company);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void getListDataTest() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        SeminarListItem item = new SeminarListItem();
        item.setCompanyName("company" + i);
        item.setPlace("place" + i);
        item.setTime("time" + i);
        mSeminarData.add(item);
    }
    if (mSeminarListAdapter == null) {
        mSeminarListAdapter = new SeminarListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, mSeminarData);
    }
    mSeminarList.setAdapter(mSeminarListAdapter);
    mSeminarListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Following is the my custom adapter.

```
public class SeminarListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SeminarListItem> {

Context mContext;
int mResId;
ArrayList<SeminarListItem> mSeminarListData;

public SeminarListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SeminarListItem> object) {
    super(context, resource, object);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResId = resource;
    this.mSeminarListData = object;
}

public void setSeminarListData(ArrayList<SeminarListItem> data) {
    this.mSeminarListData = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mSeminarListData == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return mSeminarListData.size();
    }
}

@Override
public SeminarListItem getItem(int position) {
    if (mSeminarListData == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return mSeminarListData.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.companyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_company_name);
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_time);
        holder.place = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_place);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    SeminarListItem item = mSeminarListData.get(position);
    holder.companyName.setText(item.getCompanyName());
    holder.time.setText(item.getTime());
    holder.place.setText(item.getPlace());

    return convertView;

}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView companyName;
    public TextView time;
    public TextView place;
}
}
```

While I call fuction `getListDataTest()`, it display successfully, and if I call fuction `getListData()`, it will fail. I have debugged, and found that function `getView()` in adapter will not be called.

I doubt that, if I get the argument "context" using MainActivity at a new thread, it will differ from the "context" got from the UI main thread.

Comment: i think you  have to call `getListDataTest()` inside `getListData()`

Comment: and check what value of `i` you passing in `getListDataTest()`

Comment: `getListData()` gets data from web and `getListDataTest()` generates data by myself. While I call `getListData()`, listview cannot display list item. If I call `getListDataTest()`, listview can display list item successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved it. While using RxJava to deal with multiple thread, we also should include library "RxAndroid", and let listview related operation on thread "AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()".

Comment: Yes: Never, never, never leave `onError` completely empty. It will just swallow any exceptions like the one you received for touching the `ListView` from the wrong thread. At least put `e.printStackTrace()` in there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do your listview operations, i.e. notifyDataSetChanged, on the mainthread. The simplest way to do this is to use rxandroid and add

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

before subscribing to the observable.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! It works perfectly! I have some much to learn, and I will keep learning. Thank you :)